# Pho stock turns dark

Tags: stock, vietnamese-cuisine

When making a pho stock, the onion, ginger, garlic are charred over a flame.. when I do this, whether using water or stock (unroasted bones), my pho stock turns dark.

My memory of pho in Vietnam is of a clear white stock, I was wondering how this is achieved!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [recipe](https://thewoksoflife.com/pho-vietnamese-noodle-soup/) I saw said to rinse off all the charred skin after charring the aromatic ingredients. Much of the "charred" flavor is inside the items, and this way the charcoal won't turn your stock dark.

Many other recipes, however, implied that a darker-colored stock is desirable, and none seemed to attempt at a lighter-colored stock. It is possible that the light-colored stock you remember was a different dish entirely.